# In Django rest framework , on using custom models, what value I need to give to AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication

In Django rest framework, I have different models inside model folder -

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'bootstrap3',
'rest_framework',
'myapp',
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.models.UserModel.User'
```

- myapp

  - settings

    - dev.py
  - models

    - UserModels.py
    - OrderModels.py
    - ReportingModels.py

UserModels.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, GuardianUserMixin ,PermissionsMixin):

id = models.AutoField(_('id'),unique=True,primary_key=True)
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),unique=True)
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100, blank=True)
parent_id = models.IntegerField(_('parent id'), default=0)
organization_id = models.IntegerField(_('organization id'), default=0, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined '), default=timezone.now())
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_('date modified '), default=timezone.now())
incorrect_login = models.IntegerField(_('incorrect login frequency'), default=0)
soft_delete = models.BooleanField(_('soft delete'), default=False, )
group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group', null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['last_name, first_name, email,organization_id,group_id ']

class Meta:
    app_label = 'zeocuser'
    db_table = 'zeocuser_zeocuser'
    permissions = (
        (
            ('add_user_admin', 'add user admin'),
        )
    )


objects = UserManager()
```

Now, in settings.py for AUTH_USER_MODEL if i give value as following -
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.models.UserModel.User'
it doesn't accept it and give following error -

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py", line 32, in <module>
    class LogEntry(models.Model):
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 158, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 706, in contribute_to_class
    super(ForeignObject, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only=virtual_only)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 306, in contribute_to_class
    lazy_related_operation(resolve_related_class, cls, self.remote_field.model, field=self)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 86, in lazy_related_operation
    return apps.lazy_model_operation(partial(function, **kwargs), *model_keys)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 84, in <genexpr>
    model_keys = (make_model_tuple(m) for m in models)
  File "/Users/richagupta/VirtualEnvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/utils.py", line 13, in make_model_tuple
    app_label, model_name = model.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But If I put my user model directly inside the app in a models.py file (without putting it in models folder) and give

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

It works fine. But in that case, how should I organise my other model classes. Kindly suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django expects the models to be located in the .models namespace.

As it's mentioned in point 2 at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded:

> You must define or import all models in your application’s models.py or models/**init**.py. Otherwise, the application registry may not be fully populated at this point, which could cause the ORM to malfunction.

In your case, You'll need to import the models in myapp/models/__init__.py file:

```
from .UserModels import User, <other models>
from .OrderModels import <other models>
from .ReportingModels import <other models>
```

and so on

Comment: Sure, I am facing another problem in django. To make an api with fliter capability , something like /user?email=<> , in that, In the urls.py i have     url(r'^api/v1/users/$',   UserViews.UserList.as_view(), name='userlist_view'),
    url(r'^api/v1/users/(?P<email>.+)/$', UserViews.UserList.as_view(), name='userList_view'), But /user?email=<> always go to the method corresponding to  api/v1/users/ . In views, I have added method-     def get_queryset(self):
        email = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        return User.objects.filter(email=email)
But control doesn't go there .

Comment: you should try with /users/?email=<> (note the / before the ?)

Comment: No It doesn't work.Even on trying : localhost:8000/api/v1/users/?email=abc.xyz@gmail.com/ it goes to get all users method

Comment: For more detials, please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569058/how-to-implement-filter-api-in-django-rest-framework